# Correct timing of denoting an arbitrary constant of indefinite integral

Tags: integration, constants

$$\begin{align}
A&:=\int{\arctan(x)\over 1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1} \\
&=\int\arctan(x){\mathrm{d}\over\mathrm{d}x}\arctan(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2} \\
&=\arctan(x)\arctan(x)-\int{\arctan(x)\over 1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\arctan(x)^2-A\tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
A &= \arctan(x)^2-A\tag{5}\\
2A &= \arctan(x)^2\tag{6}\\
A &= {1\over 2}\arctan(x)^2+\mathrm{const}\tag{7}\\
\end{align}$$

$$\int{\arctan(x)\over 1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x={1\over 2}\arctan(x)^2+\mathrm{const}\tag{8}$$

Comment: A constant should be added in (3). Moreover, notice that in (2) the integrand is of the form $ u'u$, which its anti-derivate is well known...

Comment: I see. Thank you.